# Convert DocumentReference to string format

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching a list of `DocumentReference` which I am fetching from firestore. It looks like this:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@4a69111d
```

However, I can't get the object using the above in the following code.

```kotlin
var loc = com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@4a69111d
var documentRef:DocumentReference = firestore.document(loc.toString())
            documentRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                if (document != null) {
                    Log.d("SHARED_PREF_VM", "DocumentSnapshot data: ${document.data}")
                }
            })
```

Can I somehow convert `com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference@4a69111d` to this form `/cities/blr/areas/alpaca`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That string is just the generic Java/JVM representation of an object when its implementation does not override `toString()`.  It is mostly meaningless and useless to an application.

If you want to convert a DocumentReference to a string in order to use later as a DocumenReference, you should use the [getPath()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference#getPath()) method on it.  That will return a string which uniquely identifies that document.  Then, you can turn that string back into a DocumentReference with [firestore.document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore#document(java.lang.String)), which.